# Slideshow using UIScrollView and AutoLayout

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiscrollview, slideshow, autolayout

I wanted to create a simple slideshow of images using an UIScrollView and I noticed that,  using the new  AutoLayout mode, the operation became way more complicated compared to iOS5. I wasn't able to find any SIMPLE and SHORT example/tutorial for accomplishing it. There was a lot of material about "pure" and "hybrid" approaches,but honestly nothing really worked for me. Maybe the material is not clear enough, maybe I'm not good enough..who knows. Anyway, I thought it could be useful sharing my finding and the consequent snippet of code which is currently doing the job for me. Here we go:

```
- (void)setupSlideshow {

    NSInteger nPhotos = [self.profilePhotos count];
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    UIImageView *imageView;
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary;
    // Create the scroll view and the image view.
    scrollView  = self.slideShow;
    CGFloat sWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat sHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, nPhotos * sWidth, sHeight)];
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    CGFloat cx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nPhotos; i++) {
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        // Add an image to the image view.
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.profilePhotos[i]]];
        CGRect imFrame = imageView.frame;
        imFrame.origin.x = cx;
        imFrame.origin.y = 0;
        imFrame.size.width = sWidth;
        imFrame.size.height = sHeight;
        imageView.frame = imFrame;
        [container addSubview:imageView];
        cx += sWidth;
    }
    container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;
    [scrollView addSubview:container];
    // Set the constraints for the scroll view and the image view.
    viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView, container);
    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[container(%f)]-0-|",cx]
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics: 0
                                                                         views:viewsDictionary]];
    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[container]-0-|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
}
```

The scrollView has been instantiated in the StoryBoard.
As you can notice, I adopted an approach based on a UIView container for the pictures I want to use which has been added to a scrollview. I have then added some constraints using the Visual Constraints Format notation. I tried to match the width of the container to the scroller's one using this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[container(==scrollView)]-0-|"]
```

but it doesn't work (to be precise it doesn't scroll but sticks to the first image), so I opted for a dynamic approach using a simple string format.

As I said, it does the job, but I'm sure I can make it way more elegant. Besides that, is it possible to fix the problem relative the dynamic width?

I hope to receive some useful feedback, in order to refine this example. I will then setup a GitHub for making it publicly available for all of those who spent 3 days banging their head against a wall...like I did.

Comment: Fair enough,but the all point is to make it working with Autolayout :)